# segments of common values in sorted arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I would like to calculate the common segments in arrays that are already sorted:

Consider the following two arrays:

```
var arr1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
var arr2 = ['a','c','d'];
```

I would like to return ['a'],['b'],['c','d']

This is not the typical intersection, maintaining the order of the array values is crucial.

Is there a simple way to do this using underscore?

Comment: are u not looking for `['b'],['a','c','d']`  ?

Comment: Not the standard intersection, the order of the values matters :)

Comment: is there a rule behind the grouping?

Comment: Groups are however they were returned by the API that provided them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably this works for you, at least with the given data.

```js
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    arr2 = ['a', 'c', 'd'],
    arr3 = [];

arr1.forEach(function (a, i) {
    if (!i || this.next) {
        arr3.push([a]);
        if (a === arr2[this.index]) {
            this.index++;
        }
        this.next = false;
        return;
    }
    if (a < arr2[this.index]) {
        arr3.push([a]);
        this.next = true;
        return;
    }
    if (a === arr2[this.index]) {
        arr3[arr3.length - 1].push(a);
        this.index++;
    }
}, { index: 0, next: false });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr3, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```